# Statement of Urysohn's lemma

Tags: general-topology

According to Wikipedia, Urysohn's lemma states that:

> "a topological space is normal if and only if any two disjoint closed subsets can be separated by a function"

But, aren't we missing something?

shouldn't it say that

> Let $X$ be a topological space in which one-point sets are closed. Then, X is normal if and only if any two disjoint closed subsets can be separated by a function?

because by definition normal spaces defined for $X$ in which singletons are closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different authors define "normal" in different ways.  Some authors define normal to include the condition that points are closed, and others define it to only mean that disjoint closed subsets have disjoint neighborhoods.  In particular, the Wikipedia article in question uses the latter definition, as evidenced by the following quote from later in the article:

> A normal space is a topological space in which any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by neighbourhoods.

Comment: But, if you use the latter definition of normality, then you don't necessarily have that normal spaces are Hausdorff, because a two-point space in the indiscrete topology is normal but not Hausdorff. Isn't that "weird" though?

Comment: Well, weirdness is subjective.  Each definition is convenient in some contexts.  Personally, I would agree with you that the definition including that points are closed is generally more useful.